# Copying folders based on values in xml/config file properties using msbuild

Tags: tfs, msbuild

We were previously using GO as our CI system and we using this code to copy folder from one location to another based on the properties pulled from a config file. We now are using TFS/MSBuild and I am at a loss on the best way to do this. I have tried xmlpeek, readfromfile, etc. Any Ideas would be great
Old GO code
    
    Starting Article Copy for ${articlexpath}

```
<foreach item="String" delim="," in="${articlelist}" property="apath">
  <echo>Directory: ${apath}</echo>
  <copy overwrite="true" todir="${ShellAppDir}\Providers\${Provider}\${Edition}\Articles">
    <fileset basedir="..\FolderName\Assets\Content\Articles">
      <include name="${apath}/**" />
    </fileset>
  </copy>
</foreach>
```

One section of the file we need to read from and copy the folder based on the ArticleID property
        
            
            1847f676-5bc6-df11-b8bb-001e0bc3c80e
            Connect a Cable Modem to Your Computer
            
            false

Comment: Are you doing these through TFS buids? if so what version of TFS?  I believe your easiest path may be to use a powershell script called at the end of your build process.  How you implement those can depend on the version of TFS you are using.

Comment: This is for an Installshield build that uses an msbuild script to build out the folders and files needed by IS to create the installer based on the values read from an xml file. Hope this helps.